# Couchbase data/disk usage and RAM/Quota usage figures

Tags: couchbase

I have zero items in my bucket and yet the Couchbase admin page is showing 61.2 mb/4GB for RAM/Quota usage and 335 MB/486 MB for data/disk usage.  I can see another bucket with 21556 items and it shows 63.4MB/66MB for Data/Disk usage.  Shouldn't I have a lower Data/Disk Usage than a bucket with items in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RAM usage figures include various internal data structures (connection buffers, internal hash tables etc.) so it's quite normal to see the RAM usage for an empty bucket to be a few 10s of MB, especially if you recently *did* have a number of documents or clients connected.

For Disk usage, as Couchbase uses an [append-only file format](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-admin/index.html#disk-throughput-and-sizing), document mutations (including deletion) will increase disk usage. There is a periodic background *compaction* task which when run will shrink down the disk files, by default this will kick in once you hit 30% fragmentation in the disk files.

Comment: You can also manually trigger compact bucket operation that should further clean up unused space and rebuild indexes.